# How can I fix the Expiring Certificates window that appears whenever I restart (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

Whenever I restart my computer, I see the following window...

[image: Expiring certificates warning]

If I check the box next to the certificates listed and click Done, I see...

[image: Error cannot find file]

This is on Windows 10 and includes software like Office (including Outlook), Visual Studio, SQL Server Management Studio, and Skype for Business.

---

In order to make the question more searchable, I'm including the text from the dialog below...

> **Expiring Certificates**
>
> The following certificates have expired or will expire soon. When a certificates expires, it is no longer considered an acceptable or usable credential. You can attempt to renew these certificates now. If you do not want to renew certificates at this time, Windows will remind you of their pending expiration each time you log on.
>
> If you do not want to be reminded to renew specific user certificates, select the checkbox next to these certificates and click Done.
> For machine certificates, please read help and contact a system administrator if this warning reappears the next time you log onto the network.

Error message...

> **Error**
>
> The system cannot find the files specified.

Comment: Which certificate store is the certificate installed in (machine or user)?  Where within the store is it located in?  There is a simple answer on why the certification cannot be found.  What process is throwing up this dialog window by the way?

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like the window is from `taskhostw.exe` called by `svchost.exe`.  When I hover over the task in Process Explorer, it says the Command Line is `taskhostw.exe USER` and the Tasks is `Certificate Service Client Task Handler [\Microsoft\Windows\CertificateServicesClient\UserTask]`.

Comment: You need to pay Mister Bill. Apart from jokes facing the same error today :)

Answer (score -2):

Reinstalling the office suite got rid of it for me. 
According to the link below this error message can be ignored. The link includes a few workarounds as well.
https://infrastructurehelp.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/lync-2010-users-receive-certificate-expiration-warning/

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful.  This answers, in it's current form, appears to be spam for the blog in question